# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Error in Android

Tags: java, android

I can`t figure out the reason why I got this error since I am new in android. The app was tested in my phone its working properly but when I uploaded it in google play and install it it always crash and when I see the ANRs & crashes I got this error below: or you may see the screen shot by click this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZBVh.jpg

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 

  at ce.b (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19274083@19.2.74 (100408-265167076):3)

  at cb.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19274083@19.2.74 (100408-265167076):3)

  at cd.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19274083@19.2.74 (100408-265167076):14)

  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.aj.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19274083@19.2.74 (100408-265167076):4)

  at bf.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19274083@19.2.74 (100408-265167076):22)

  at bf.run (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19274083@19.2.74 (100408-265167076):8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 

  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)

  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)

  at ad.loadClass (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@19274083@19.2.74 (100408-265167076):4)

  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Comment: check your classpath. looks like you're missing some library, or getting it with a different version than expected so you miss this class

Comment: Try deleting the app from your phone, restart the device, and re-download the app from Google Play.

Comment: @dominicoder - done doing that thing but I still got that error. I’ve tested it to multiple mobile phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know if this thing will work. I’ve been searching with regards to this concern, according to them I will just add to my AndroidManifest this code below

```
<uses-library
```

android:name=“org.apache.http.legacy”
android:required=“false” />

hope this will fix my concern. I will try it later once I get back home.